# Assetic, twitter bootstrap and less

Tags: node.js, symfony, twitter-bootstrap, assets

Config:

```
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    read_from:      %kernel.root_dir%/../public
    filters:
        less:
            node: /usr/bin/node
            node_paths: [/usr/local/lib/node_modules]
```

Twig template:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
{% stylesheets filter='less'
    '@MyBundle/Resources/public/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less'
%}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

This works almost good.

I have one problem, there are no images, they are referenced relative url("../img/glyphicons-halflings.png") but they are not there.

And one question, this works with node.js, but what if I don't have node.js on production server, will it work if I just upload compiled css?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use the cssrewrite filter too, like this:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
{% stylesheets filter='less,cssrewrite'
    '/bundles/mybundle/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less'
%}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

Don't forget to publish your assets with this command:

```
app/console assets:install --symlink web
```

And to answer your final question, yes uploading the compiled css will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any doc where I can see how can I configure this filter?

Comment: I don't recall where I found it... just putting `cssrewrite: ~` in your config.yml should enable it.

Comment: Now it references it with `url("../Resources/public/bootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings.png")`, which is one step in good direction, but still 404. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks, but only when I copy twitter bootstrap to `/public/bundles/...`, I would like to store it inside my bundle. Is that possible?

Comment: Wow, didn't know about that option, thanks! Actually it works wuth or without --symlink option, it's just important to dump them.

Comment: Not documented at all, but quite important indeed ^^

Comment: I got problem in production mode, it throws `[2012-05-27 20:26:16] request.CRITICAL: Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("There is no "less" filter.") in "MyBundle:Backend:layout.html.twig". (uncaught exception) at vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php line 541 [] []` which is very strange, my dev and live conf are very similar, and they both import main config where I defined this filter.

Comment: I think you should write another question, this has little to do with this one, hasn't it?

Comment: Maybe, yeah. I need to make sure first. Thank you very much, I learned a lot from your answer!

Comment: I had some old cache files for production, removing them fixed this issue.